# Typescript Script, ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND, running a script with ts-node that imports other files

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am pulling my hair out over a very simple usecase. I have a monorepo and inside the monorepo I have a package that has some utilities for my database and the schemas. I want to write a script that will seed the DB and I decided to use `ts-node` to run this script. Now this seems simple enough, I just want to run a file, but I cannot get it to work. I've had `module not found` errors, `unknown file type .ts` and many variations of these.

My file structure

```
src/ <- db helpers
scripts/ <- here's the script file I want to run
tsconfig.json
```

My `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": { <- I tried using relative paths and absolute
            "@company/db/*": [
                "src/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "include": [ <- make sure everything is included
        "index.ts",
        "src/**/*",
        "scripts/**/*"
    ],
    "ts-node": {
        "esm": true,  <- make sure esm is set
        "require": [ <- I tried using relative paths and absolute
            "tsconfig-paths/register"
        ]
    }
}

// tsconfig.base.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true
  }
}
```

```
{
    "name": "@company/db",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "main": "./index.ts",
    "type": "module", <- this is also set
    "types": "./index.ts",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
         "seed": "pnpm with-env ts-node ./scripts/seed.ts",
```

Also tried adding `NODE_PATH=./` to match base path

The script I am trying to run

```js
import { randomUUID } from "crypto";
import { db, connectDB } from "../src/db"; <- tried absolute paths as well with aliases
import { employees } from "../src/schemas";
```

The `../src/db` also imports other `.ts` files and the other `packages` from the monorepo

```
> @company/db@0.1.0 with-env /app/packages/db
> dotenv -e ../../.env -- "ts-node" "./scripts/seed.ts"

/app/node_modules/ts-node/dist-raw/node-internal-modules-esm-resolve.js:366
    throw new ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND(
          ^
CustomError: Cannot find module '/app/packages/db/src/db' imported from /app/packages/db/scripts/seed.ts
```

Example of te error I am seeing, I've seen others as well. I tried all of the solutions from [github issues](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/422), I tried using `esrun` and other alternatives. This seems like a common usecase but I have no idea why is it this difficult to setup

Answer (score 1):

Use [tsx](https://github.com/privatenumber/tsx) for such scripts.

Hopefully, [bun.sh](https://bun.sh) would be a better alternative soon. It isn't on Windows yet but works everywhere else.

Comment: Yeah this was before Bun was a thing (or took off at least), I am using it for any new scripts or simple projects in node. Life saver

Comment: @Nikola-Milovic hopefully, windows release comes soon enough so i can finally use it. but there will be a lot of bugs still so maybe need a year or more to use it everywhere.